# shell script to batch replace specific string in .csv file

Tags: shell, batch-processing

I want to replace some strings in my raw csv file for further use and I search for the internet and create the script so far. But it seems they doesn't work. Hope anyone can help me

The csv file is like this and I want to delete "^M" and "# Columns: " so that I can read my file.

```
# Task: bending1^M
# Frequency (Hz): 20^M
# Clock (millisecond): 250^M
# Duration (seconds): 120^M
# Columns: time,avg_rss12,var_rss12,avg_rss13,var_rss13,avg_rss23,var_rss23^M
```

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function scandir(){
cd `dirname $0`
echo `pwd`
local cur_dir parent_dir workir
workdir=$1
cd ${workdir}

if [ ${workdir}="/" ]
then 
    cur_dir=""
else
    cur_dir=$(pwd)
fi

for dirlist in $(ls ${cur_dir})
do
    if test -d ${dirlist}
    then
        cd ${dirlist}
        scandir ${cur_dir}/${dirlist}
        cd ..
    else
        vi ${cur_dir}/${dirlist} << EOF
        :%s/\r//g
        :%s/\#\ Columns:\ //g
        :wq
        EOF
    fi
done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your whole script looks like just:

```
find "$workdir" -type f | xargs -n1 sed -i -e 's/\r//g; s/^# Columns://'
```

Notes to your script:

- Check your scripts for validity on https://www.shellcheck.net/
- The of `<< EOF` here document is invalid. The closing word `EOF` *has to* start from the beginning of the line inside the script:

```
    vi ${cur_dir}/${dirlist} << EOF
    :%s/\r//g
    :%s/\#\ Columns:\ //g
    :wq
EOF
#^^ no spaces in front of EOF, also no spaces/tabs after EOF
# the whole line needs to be exactly 'EOF'
```

There cannot be any spaces, tabs in front of it. Also, I don't think `vi` is not the best tool to run substitutions on a file, also I don't know how it acts with tabs or spaces infront of `:`. You may want to try to run it without whitespace characters in front of `:`:

```
    vi ${cur_dir}/${dirlist} << EOF
:%s/\r//g
:%s/\#\ Columns:\ //g
:wq
EOF
```

- Backticks ` are [deprecated](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete), less readable and don't allow for easy nesting. Use `$( ... )` command substitution instead.
- echo `pwd` is just invalid use of echo, just use `pwd`.
- `for dirlist in $(ls` [parsing ls output is bad](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use `find` command instead, or if you have to, shell globulation, ie. `for dirlist in *`.
- `if [ ${workdir}="/" ]` is invalid. This tests if the string `"${workdir}=/` is not null. Bash is space aware, it needs a space between `=` and operands. It should be `if [ "${workdir}" = "/" ]`.
- [Always quote your variables](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). Don't `cd ${dirlist}` do `cd "${dirlist}"` and so on.

Comment: `xargs` is not necessary (`find` can execute commands), and the idiomatic way to skip/delete lines in `sed` is to use `/pattern/d`

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Well posted answer are corrects, but I would recommand this syntax:

```
find "$1" -type f -name '*.csv' -exec sed -e 's/\r$//;s/^# Columns: //' -i~ {} +
```

- Using `+` instead of `\;` at end of find command will permit `sed` to work on many files at once, reducing forks and make whole job quicker.
- The `~` after `-i` option will rename existing files by appending tilde at end of names instead of deleting them.
- Using `-type f` will ensure working on files only (no symlinks, dirs, socket, fifos, devices...)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the entire script to one command, and you do not have to use Vim to process the files:

```
find ${workdir} -name '*.csv' -exec sed -i -e 's/\r$//; /^#/d' '{}' \;
```

Explanation:

- `find <dir> -name <pattern> -exec <command> \;` will search `<dir> for files matching``and execute`` on each file.  You want to search for CSV files and do something with them (run a command on them).
- The command run on every (CSV) file that was found will be `sed -i -e 's/\r$//; /^#/d'`.  This means to edit the files in-place (`-i`) and run two transformations on them.  `s/\r$//` will remove the `^M` from each line, and `/^#/d` will remove all lines that start with a `#`.
- `'{}'` is replaced with the files found by `find` and `\;` marks the end of the command run by `find` (see the `find` manual page for this).

Most of your script emulates part of the `find` command.  That is not a good idea.

Also, for simple text processing, it is easier and faster to use `sed` instead of invoking an editor such as Vim.

Comment: Consider `+` end tag to `-exec` option of `find` command, instead of `\;`

Comment: @F.Hauri Yes, that would be slightly more efficient because it would invoke `sed` only once for all the files; however, I wanted to make the example as simple as possible and not use the more advanced functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

I want to replace 'some string' with 'something'. So I used this command to replace the text into the csv file.

```
sed -i '' 's/old string/new string/g' data.csv
```